# robot framework info message not printing

Tags: python, logging, robotframework

My python code generates a log file using logging framework and all `INFO` messages are captured in the log file. I integrated my program with ROBOT framework and now the log file is not generated. Instead the `INFO` messages are printed in the `log.html`. I understand this is because robot existing logger is being called and hence `INFO` are directed to `log.html`. I don't want the behavior to change, I still want the user defined log file to be generated separately with just the `INFO` level messages.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please describe how do you create and use your logger and so on? Are you using default logger?

Comment: Please include whether this is using the robot logger interface or the Listener API?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed now, which was a very minor one. But am still analyzing it deeper, will update when I am clear on the exact cause.
This was the module that I used,

```
def call_logger(logger_name, logFile):
        level = logging.INFO
        l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        if not getattr(l, 'handler_set', None):
                formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(message)s')
                fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(logFile, mode = 'a')
                fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
                streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
                streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
                l.setLevel(level)
                l.addHandler(fileHandler)
                l.addHandler(streamHandler)
                l.handler_set = True
```

When I changed the parameter "logFile" to a different name "log_file" it worked.
Looks like "logFile" was a built in robot keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Python Code --> Logging Library --> "Log File"

RobotFramework --> Python Code --> Logging Library --> by default "log.html"

When you run using python code it will allow you set log file name.
But when you run using robotframework, the file is by default set to log.html (since robot uses the same logging library internally that you are using) so your logging function is overridden by that of robotframework.

That is why you see it in log.html instead of your file.

You can also refer [Robot Framework not creating file or writing to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044060/robot-framework-not-creating-file-or-writing-to-it/41054910#41054910)

Hope it helps!